# Which C# command line parser library should I use?

Tags: c#, command-line

I want to develop a non-interactive command line application in C#. There are some libaries available for command line parsing:

- [Cocona](https://github.com/mayuki/Cocona)
- [commanddotnet](https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/commanddotnet)
- [commandline](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline)
- [CommandLineUtils](https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils)
- [CliFx](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliFx)
- [dotnet/command-line-api](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api)
- [Mono.Options](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options)
- [NDesk Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options)

I've never developed a command line application in C# yet. I would be grateful for experience people gathered using one or several of these libraries. Interesting are the non-obvious things to consider like maintainability, etc. instead of github stars, contributer count, etc. I'd favour a framework with support for testing, logging, etc. if it has a lot of adopters and contributres. However a plain library would be fine as well.

**EDIT**: I've added a summary of package characteristics and features [here](https://gist.github.com/fkromer/91b774e01270e675ba1a921703eea378).

Answer (score 1):

Note that Microsoft now has System.CommandLine for .NET 6.0 and above. Find it here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/

Comment: Please explain why